# Why doesn't figwidth parameter work with pyplot.subplots() call?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to create a subplot figure in matplotlib, specifying only the width (using `figwidth(float)` rather than `figsize(float, float)`), assuming that the height will have some default value. When calling `pyplot.subplots()`, the `**fig_kw` parameter is [passed to the `pyplot.figure()` call](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

> All additional keyword arguments are passed to the pyplot.figure
> call.

which in turn [passes any additional keyword arguments to the `Figure` constructor](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure). One of the valid Figure constructor keyword arguments is [`figwidth=float`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#module-matplotlib.figure). However, when this is done via the passing mentioned above (subplots(figwidth) **-->** figure(figwidth) **-->** Figure(figwidth)) an AttributeError is raised:

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'bbox_inches'
```

The MWE to recreate this is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(figwidth=4)
```

I thought perhaps this was due to needing to set the height and width together so I tried calling `pyplot.figure()` directly with parameters `figheight=3` and `figwidth=4`, but got the same AttirbuteError.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Interestingly you can create a figure, `f = plt.figure()`, then call `f.set_figwidth(4)` on it without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually get the same error when I try to run `plt.figure(figwidth=2)`.

Just use `figsize`, which works with both `plt.figure()` and `plt.subplots()`. You can simply pass the default value:

```
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'][0], 3))
```

Comment: Hi @cheersmate, it was the parameter that has the issue not its value. As I said in the question I'm trying to set the width only and have matplotlib set the height dynamically so `figsize()` doesn't achieve what I want.

Comment: @compuphys You can use the default value, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @cheersmate. Doesn't this still force a static figheight set to the default value though? I'm trying to get a fixed width with a dynamic height.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Updated my comment now

Comment: What do you mean by fixed and dynamic? You can resize the figure to any shape if you open it in a window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251074/discussion-between-compuphys-and-cheersmate).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `figwidth` and `figheight` are initialized in the superclass through the `kwargs`. This results in the call of the method `set_figwidth` ([source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c23ccdde6f0f8c071b09a88770e24452f2859e99/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L3019)) that look like this:

```py
def set_figwidth(self, val, forward=True):
    self.set_size_inches(val, self.get_figheight(), forward=forward)
```

It calls `self.get_figheight()` ([source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c23ccdde6f0f8c071b09a88770e24452f2859e99/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L3000)) which looks like this:

```py
def get_figheight(self):
    return self.bbox_inches.height
```

And this is the line that throws the error when it tries to access `self.bbox_inches` which is initialized after the superclass ([here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c23ccdde6f0f8c071b09a88770e24452f2859e99/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L2477)).

So it's not possible to pass the value in the constructor, but you can set them on the initialized object:

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots()
f.set_figwidth(10)
```

Comment: So it this simply an error in the documentation?

Comment: In the documentation, it probably lists all attributes that have a setter method. I think it is more like an oversight.